# Is there an action cost to draw a weapon?

Tags: call-of-cthulhu-7e

In Call of Cthulhu (7e), is there an action cost associated with drawing and/or sheathing a weapon? If so, would a pirate with a brace of flintlock pistols be able to thus have one attack per round until he runs out of loaded pistols (in that he can switch weapons without cost to use a loaded pistol instead)? Or would he have to spend a turn switching guns?

Answer (score 3):

The basic rules do not have an action cost for drawing a weapon. In addition, the example of combat supports the concept with this excerpt from page 111:

> **Rodger’s action:**
>   No action has been taken against Rodger this round,
>   so he is free to stand up and act. He draws a throwing dagger from his
>   belt and throws it at the cultist’s back. This is a thrown weapon
>   attack; the Keeper decides that the cultist will not be able to dodge
>   it because he is unaware of the attack (see Ranged and Thrown Weapons,
>   page 108), but Rodger still has to roll to hit.

The optional rules beginning on page 123 provide a nice bonus to initiative when you begin the round with an already drawn firearm, but even the optional rules don't require an action to draw a weapon.